# Given two functions $f$ and $g$ whose derivatives $f'$ and $g'$ satisfy : $f'(x)=g(x), g'(x)=-f(x),f(0)=0, g(0)=1$ for all $x$ in an interval $J$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given two functions $f$ and $g$ whose derivatives $f'$ and $g'$ satisfy : $f'(x)=g(x), g'(x)=-f(x),f(0)=0, g(0)=1$ for all $x$ in an interval $J$. $~~~\cdots(A)$

(a) Prove that $f^2(x)+g^2(x)=1 ~\forall~x \in J $

(b) Let $F$ and $G$ be another pair of functions in $J$ which satisfy the given conditions $(A)$. Prove that $f(x)=F(x)$ and $g(x)=G(x)$.

**Attempt:** $(a)$

$f^2(x)+g^2(x)+c=   2[ ~\int f(x) ~d ~(f(x)) +  ~\int g(x) ~d ~(g(x))~]$

$=2 [ ~\int f(x) ~ g(x)~ dx -  ~\int g(x) ~f(x)~ dx~]$

$ = 0$

Applying the initial conditions, we get :$f^2(x)+g^2(x)=1$

$(b)$

Consider : $h(x)=[f(x)-F(x)]^2+[g(x)-G(x)]^2$

If we prove that $h(x)=0~\forall~x \in J$, then $f(x)=F(x), g(x)=G(x)$

Expanding : $h(x)=f^2(x)+F^2(x)-2f(x)F(x)+g^2(x)+G^2(x)-2g(x)G(x)$

$=2[1-f(x)F(x)-g(x)G(x)]$

> How do I prove that $f(x)F(x)+g(x)G(x) =1$?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint

Let

$$H(x)=f(x)F(x)+g(x)G(x)$$
since
$$F'=G,G'=-F,f'=g,g'=-f$$
so

\begin{align*}H'(x)&=f'(x)F(x)+f(x)F'(x)+g'(x)G(x)+g(x)G'(x)\\
&=g(x)F(x)+f(x)G(x)+g'(x)G(x)+g(x)G'(x)\\
&=g(x)[F(x)+G'(x)]+G(x)[f(x)+g'(x)]\\
&=0
\end{align*}
so 
$$H(x)=H(0)=f(0)F(0)+g(0)G(0)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

You have already defined
$$
h(x)=[f(x)-F(x)]^2+[g(x)-G(x)]^2
$$
You only need to differentiate this equation:

$$
\begin{align}
h'(x) &= 2 [f(x)-F(x)][f'(x)-F'(x)] + 2 [g(x)-G(x)][g'(x)-G'(x)] \\
 &= 2 [f(x)-F(x)][g(x)-G(x)] - 2 [g(x)-G(x)][f(x)-F(x)] \\
 &= 0
\end{align}
$$

so that $h$ is constant and therefore identical to $h(0) = 0$.

Comment: @Wanderer: You are welcome!